# Android deep links - Multiple re-direct with same url

Tags: android, deep-linking

In my application i am using deep links to navigate to Particular activity. I want to navigate to different activities with same basePrefix with different context path at end.

```
<intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.mycompany.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/profile/friendslist"/>
        </intent-filter>


 <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.mycompany.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/profile/friendslist/details"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://www.mycompany.com//profile/friendslist" com.mycompany.sample : It launches FriendsListFragment

./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://www.mycompany.com//profile/friendslist/details" com.mycompany.sample : It also launches FriendsListFragment instead of FriendsListDetailsFragment

What i want to do is

/profile/friendslist/: should open **FriendsList**

/profile/friendslist/details?id=1234 **should navigate to FriendDetails**

**Anyone suggest how we make use of android:pathPrefix to navigate to different screens based on context path?**

Comment: I never did but you can override onNewIntent method in your activity. Then read on the intent the method getData to get your link. Then do with it what you have to do to open the correct fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You may opt for a `pathPattern` in the first `intent-filter`

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.mycompany.com"
                android:pathPattern="/profile/friendslist$"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The **$** indicates end of string, which would drop the "/profile/friendslist/details" case

OR Rather, go for `android:path="/profile/friendslist"` which looks for an exact match.